# SwiftUI- can't drag a view outside of a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swiftui

Here is a very simplified version of my layout. I have a text view that I'm able to drag around...

```
struct DragView: View {
    var text:String

    @State var dragAmt = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding(15)
            .background(Color.orange)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .padding(5)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 60, alignment: .leading)
            .offset(dragAmt)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                    .onChanged {
                        self.dragAmt = CGSize(width: $0.translation.width, height: $0.translation.height)
                }
                .onEnded {_ in
                    self.dragAmt = CGSize.zero
            })
    }
}
```

And then I arrange these views like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    DragView(text: "hi")
                    DragView(text: "hi")
                    DragView(text: "hi")
                }
            }
            Divider()
            VStack {
                DragView(text: "hi")
                DragView(text: "hi")
                DragView(text: "hi")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The views that are not in the ScrollView act as expected, and I can drag them around the entire screen. The views that are in the ScrollView, however, will disappear if brought outside the bounds of the ScrollView.

Why does this occur? Is there any way to enable these views to be dragged outside the ScrollView?

Comment: You drag, you just don't see it because `ScrollView` clips its content view. Stacks do not, by default. If you add `.clipped()` for bottom `VStack` you'll see the same.

Comment: @SCooney were you able to come up with a working solution using a ZStack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this occur?

You drag, you just don't see it because `ScrollView` clips its content view. Stacks do not, by default. If you add `.clipped()` for bottom `VStack` you'll see the same.

> Is there any way to enable these views to be dragged outside the
>   ScrollView?

Solution might be using ZStack. Say on drag you hide one view in ScrollView and show same out-of ScrollView at the same global location, so visually it would behave as would drag original.